# Error Checking for a User Input File

Tags: error-handling, common-lisp, user-input

I've written (and mostly debugged) a program that processes a user input file made up of macro calls. I'd like to now add thorough error checking on the user input file. Is there a general best practices approach for performing syntactic & semantic error checking on such a file? Three basic approaches I can think of are 1) to write a separate preprocessing program to validate the file, 2) to specify a BNF and use an off-the-shelf compiler-compiler as a preprocessor, or 3) to integrate error checks into the existing program. The third approach seems like it might be better, since it may enable deeper semantic checks? I would like to know the pros & cons for these and other approaches.

Comment: Could your input be read as successive Lisp forms or do you need a parser?

Comment: I don't know if independent parsing at the top level (other than normal compiling) would be useful, since the input file is just a listing of lisp forms (individual macro calls, which require processing in-order due to dependencies). However, the user information provided in some of the macro calls consists of short language-like logic "programs", which are used by the baseline program in an attempt to solve the user's specified problem. So there is some parsing involved. But the code for processing the various logic program elements is already part of the working baseline, coded in lisp.

Comment: I don't know if this is “answerable” in a Stack Overflow format, but definitely would need a small example — but — I've done a few similar things and just littered the macroexpanders with validation. The less “sophisticated” the caller is expected to be, the more prolific and verbose the input validation; usually lots of `Assert` and `Check-Type` with verbose, detailed error messages in there.

Comment: That means you can discard option #2. I don't see the need for #1 either, you could end up with two diverging tools. If you don't see a problem with users writing directly Common Lisp code into input files (that could be useful), then you can directly check that your code is well-formed, like always: either inside the macro if possible, or at runtime. If you want to ensure the user can only use the language you offer her, define a whitelist of known symbols and ban all others, use a minimal readtable, etc...  Is your code similar to what is done with cffi-grovel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you coredump & BRFennPocock for the benefit of your experience. I'll take your advice and embed the error checks in the existing program, although it is sure to be an error^2 prone task to try to catch everything. There is no advance whitelist, but I could build one from the user's input, and then check for consistency among all uses (e.g., to cover misspellings). The majority of the asserts & check-types look like they will occur at load time. Thanks again.